# Geometry nodes: remove excessive instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dQPElZoMjgxbcr-j7H4tlquCiJ1Z0PuV/view?usp=sharing

I can't figure out for the life of me to remove excessive instances where **a vertex has neighbors.** In other words I've now managed to place the traffic sign where I want it, with the correct rotation, but I don't want it to be there at all at the intersections. So in this specific example file there are those 3 problem intersections where I don't want to for the signs to be at all.

I've tried to sample the original vertexes to only include those that have no vertex neighbors but then I couldn't get the rotation to work.

I've excluded the working road generation at the top of the node tree, that doesn't need any doctoring.

No idea how to do this. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an over simplified solution .....

Create a vertex group from the vertices where you want there to be lights and use that in a **Named Attribute** node connected up to the **Instance on Points** node.

1. In edit mode, select the vertices where you want there to be traffic lights.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to create a new vertex group.
3. In the Data properties tab > Vertex Groups rename the new group to **Lights**.
4. In the geo node editor add a Named Attribute node.
5. From the Name field drop-down select **Lights**.
6. Connect the Attribute output to the Selection input of the Instance on Points node.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! While this isn't the best solution for this particular problem (I want it to be automatic) it's an awesome technique which I wasn't aware of that allows hand-picking vertexes to place instances on. Thanks for that!